# Javascript checking country code keeps refreshing constantly

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current code checks the country code and then changes the drop down value before submitting it for the things to refresh in right currency pricing, but I've tried things like, putting `return;` to stop it after running it once and moving `return;` on different line with no luck. I even combined the `.val` line with `.change()` thinking maybe having it on separate lines was running it multiple times and refreshing it multiple times.

Here is my code;

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://ipinfo.io/json",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(location) {


    if (location.country === 'AU') {
     $(".shopify-currency-form select").val("AUD").change();
} else if (location.country === 'AR') {
     $(".shopify-currency-form select").val("ARS");
} else if (location.country === 'CA') {
   $(".shopify-currency-form select").val("CAD");
} else if (location.country === 'US') {
   $(".shopify-currency-form select").val("USD").change();
}
return;
}
} );

$('.shopify-currency-form select').on('change', function() {
$(this)
    .parents('form')
    .submit();
return;
});
```

Comment: So you change the input and refresh the page.   What are you expecting `.submit()` to do, other than submit (and refresh).   You probably want to check what the existing value is before changing it and re-submitting - ie, if it's the same, don't reload.   Question: Why are you calling submit()?

Comment: @freedomn-m but it keeps reloading constantly, I just want to submit one time.

Comment: @freedomn-m already explained why that is happening.  Step through it: 1) page loads, your AJAX runs; 2) it gets a location, sets the drop down value, and triggers a change; 3) Your `.on('change' ...` handler notices that change, and submits the form the select is part of; 4) Presumably that form redirects/reloads to the new language page; 5) The new language page loads, and ... goto 1).